# Using \foreach of the forarray package to draw a path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a graph of values I defined in an array using `\draw`with TikZ.
I am having troubles including the part of the draw-command generated by an `\ForEach` -loop (forarray-package), which works fine on its own.

Problem is at l.16 "! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?."

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{forarray}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\DefineArrayVar{leist}{@}{,}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}{,}{8,7,8,9,7,6,9,9,8,9,9}

\newcommand{\coord}[1]{ --  (#1,\csname leist@#1\endcsname)}

\ForEach{,}{\coord{\thislevelitem}}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) \ForEach{,}{\coord{\thislevelitem}}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the standard `\foreach` provide by TikZ:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)
\foreach \x/\y in {1/7,2/8,3/9,4/7,5/6,6/9,7/9,8/8,9/9,10/9}
  { -- (\x,\y) } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem with `\ForEach` is that it requires expansions and assignments that TikZ can't perform when doing a `\draw`. Its own `\foreach` has been specially designed for this purpose (and has a friendlier syntax).